# binary image manipulation in C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have a set of binary images from a camera and pre-thresholded by the camera. Then I use OpenCV to find contours in each image and the coordinates of the contour centers.

But the problem I have is, this kind of process is very slow. The camera is working at 170 fps with a resolution of 2048*1088.

I know the amount of data is huge when I do this in real time. Is there any good libraries I can use to speed it up because all I need are coordinates. I need to throw away all the grayscale information and extract just the coordinates of the center of the contours in each image.

I would be grateful if someone can offer me and idea.

As requested in comments, part of my code is added here:

the image acquisition part

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xiApiPlusOcv.hpp"
#include <ctime>

xiAPIplusCameraOcv cam;
Mat frame;
vector<Mat> frames;
...
cam.StartAcquisition();
startTime = clock();

for (int j = 0; j < 600; j++)
{
    frame = cam.GetNextImageOcvMat();
    frames.push_back(frame.clone());

    frame.release();
}
cam.StopAcquisition();
cam.Close();
```

I am using a CMOS mono camera from XIMEA and here I sampled 600 frames by RAM buffering from the camera. The acquisition seed can reach up to 170 fps. And all the other processing I put then after this as:

```
vector<Mat> masks(frames.size());
for (int s = 0; s < frames.size(); s++)
{
    cvtColor(frames[s], masks[s], CV_GRAY2BGR);
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(frames[s], contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<Moments> M(contours.size());
    vector<Point2f> MC(contours.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        M[i] = moments(contours[i]);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        MC[i] = Point2f(M[i].m10 / M[i].m00, M[i].m01 / M[i].m00);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Calculate the area of each contour
        double area = contourArea(contours[i]);
        // Ignore contours that are too small or too large
        if (area < 1e2 || 1e5 < area) continue;
        // Draw each contour only for visualisation purposes
        drawContours(masks[s], contours, static_cast<int>(i), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, hierarchy, 0);
        circle(masks[s], MC[i], 4, Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1);
    }
}
```

If I do the contours finding offline, just like what is shown above, I am happy with the results. But only a very short video, say several minutes, can be recorded, which means longer monitoring is not possible.

And if I move the processing into a indefinite loop along with the acquisition, it only gives me 30-40 fps, which is not acceptable.

The number of desired contours in my ROI is about 10. 
The ultimate goal of my application is to monitor several flying objects within the frame at a distance of about 50m. And coordinates of them are all that matter I think.

I am running this on a laptop with i7-5500U 2.4GHz CPU.

Update: 
here is a binarized image from the camera monitoring a bumble bee during a very basic trial. There could be tens of flying insects within the camera frame in the normal trials.
[one binarized frame of the captured bumble bee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCXtP.png)

Comment: Please provide sample images and details of your environment. Are there multiple objects in each image?

Comment: "170 fps with a resolution of 2048*1088." I am not sure if it can get any faster. Maybe if it was multithreaded or moved on the GPU even better.

Comment: Showing your code will also help

Comment: What interface does it use to run at 3Gb/s? And what CPU is processing your frames?

Comment: Does your application _really_ need 170fps at 2K resolution?  I suggest you reduce either the fps, or the resolution before doing any processing.  Rescale and interpolate your contour center coordinates after processing if needed.  OpenCV is probably your best bet already.

Comment: I have edited my question and added some code. Hope you get notified. And also I'm sorry about my lack of information, I am new here xD.

Comment: Can you show sample images? Are your objects large in the frame? If so, you could maybe down-res your image for the initial phases. Your CPU is not very beefy, so you probably couldn't hope for even a 50% reduction in processing time by multi-threading.

Comment: As you haven’t shared any images I can only guess, but this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692085/2836621

Comment: Your fps combined with the hi res are not realistic.  You should start with lower numbers, like 30fps at 1920x1080, this should already keep your processor quite busy.  Then optimize to get better performance.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I understand what you mean. Well maybe what I'm doing now is t prove the basic concept. I'll need even higher fps in later stages as I need to monitor flying insects in a specific area, say a small garden. I'll need about 500 fps camera recording to beat twice the wingbeat frequency. So may be a development board like a NVIDIA Jetson is all I need?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hi, I've uploaded a sample image, please check.

Comment: @ZacharySun  Yes, you will definitely need a GPU based solution.  But if all you really need is a proof of concept at hi res and high speed, for detailed things like wing movement, you can use 'slowed down' recordings and get a god idea of the crunching power you'll need.  One of the parameters like resolution, sample frequency or time itself will have to give to fit on your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

There are *a lot* of things really wierd in your code (see below). 
However:

You can compute the centroids simply calling `connectedComponentsWithStats`:

```
vector<Mat> frames;
...
cv::Mat1i labels;
cv::Mat1i stats;
cv::Mat1d centroids;

for(size_t i=0; i<frames.size(); ++i) 
{
    // centroids will contain in each row the coordinates x,y of the centroids.
    int n_labels = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(frame[i], labels, stats, centroids);                

    // Remember that label 0 is the background... not really useful.
    for(int j=1; j<n_labels; ++j)  
    {
        // Filter by area
        int area = stats(j, cv::CC_STAT_AREA);
        if (area < 1e2 || 1e5 < area) continue;     

        // Do something with the centroid
        cv::Point2d centroid(centroids(j,0), centroids(j,1));
        ...
    } 
}
```

---

- I suppose your images are of type `CV_8UC1` since you are using them like so. Otherwise call `cv::Mat1b temp; cvtColor(frame[i], temp, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);` and then use `temp`.
- You actually never binarize the image.
- Why are you converting gray to rgb in `cvtColor(frames[s], masks[s], CV_GRAY2BGR);`? Masks are single channel!
- Most of what your function is doing is for debug. You should avoid this stuff for critical code.
- `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` for finding contours will waste a lot of space.
- Just use `connectedComponentWithStats` which is much faster than `findContours`, and already gives you the area and the centroid of each blob.

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply. The binarization was done by the FPGA of the camera before transmitting to my computer and the reason I convert the frames to masks as BGR is I want the contours marked by red circles not black or white xD. Or if you have any good ideas please let me know. For the other suggestions you gave, I will dig more into that. Also, you mentioned most of my function is doing for the debug, I don't get it, could you be more specific. Thanks a lot!