# Find the coordinate of a specific text in an image

Tags: image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to segment the questions in the below image. The only clue I have is the number with the bold text which is indented by a tab space. I am trying to find the bold numbering (4,5,6 in this case) so that I can get the x and y of them and segment the image into 3 separate questions. How to get these or how to approach this problem.

I am using scikit image for image processing

[image]

Comment: Are the fonts and sizes of those numbers fixed and unchanging?

Comment: @MarkSetchell oh no it can vary. But there surely be some padding between questions.

Comment: This should give you some ideas on how to find the gaps between the questions - squidge the entire image till it is one pixel wide and the same height as the original image then you will find horizontal white lines that go all the way across the image... https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692085/2836621

Comment: Thanks. The approach is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Your image looks quite simple so texts can be segmented quite easily with contour detection around the dilated components. Here are detailed steps:

1) Binarize the image and invert it for easy morphological operations.

2) Dilate the image in horizontal directions only using long horizontal kernal say (20, 1) shape kernal.

3) Find contours of all the connected components and get their coordinates.

4) Use these bounding boxes dimensional information and their coordinates to segment the questions.

Here is the Python implementation of the same:

```
# Text segmentation 
import cv2
import numpy as np

rgb = cv2.imread(r'D:\Image\st4.png')
small = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#threshold the image
_, bw = cv2.threshold(small, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# get horizontal mask of large size since text are horizontal components
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20, 1))
connected = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# find all the contours
_, contours, hierarchy,=cv2.findContours(connected.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#Segment the text lines
for idx in range(len(contours)):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[idx])
    cv2.rectangle(rgb, (x, y), (x+w-1, y+h-1), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Output image:
[image]